# Not able to search user specific contents in Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Not able to search user specific contents in Instagram, Earlier I able to do that. It stopped working out of sudden.
I was using user search API for that

Comment: @samuel To avoid such question I added that notification, I answered this, Please enable this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49663993/instagram-facebook-deprecating-many-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more sudden change from Insatagram, 
User search endpoints are deprecated immediately, with some other endpoints. It's effective from 4th April.

User Search:

```
GET /users/{user-id}

GET /users/{user-id}/media/recent

GET /users/self/media/liked

GET /users/search
```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/

Comment: Thanks this info is very helpful