# Instagram/Facebook deprecating many APIs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

This is not a question but a notification, which will help many Instagram & Facebook app developers, It will avoid many unnecessary questions.

> To continuously improve Instagram users' privacy and security, we are accelerating the deprecation of Instagram API Platform, making the following changes effective immediately. We understand that this may affect your business or services, and we appreciate your support in keeping our platform secure.
>
> These capabilities will be disabled immediately (previously set for July 31, 2018 or December 11, 2018 deprecation). The following will be deprecated according to the timeline we shared previously:
>
> - Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a user's behalf on December 11, 2018
> - Basic - to read a user’s own profile info and media in early 2020
>
> *- https://www.instagram.com/developer*

and

> #### An Update on Our Plans to Restrict Data Access on Facebook
>
> Today, we want to update you on the changes we’re making to better protect your Facebook information. We expect to make more changes over the coming months — and will keep you updated on our progress. Here are the details of the nine most important changes we are making.
>
> *- https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access*

Comment: Thanks for the notification! However, this is off-topic.